# Merging two or more n-ary trees

Tags: tree

How to merge two or more n-ary trees into one single n-ary tree? The nodes in the same levels must be placed in the same level in the resultant tree.(Thanks in advance!)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is the structure of each node?